# Generate Kernel Configuration from System Specification

Tags: linux, configuration, compilation, kernel, driver

Are there any tools which can generate the Kernel Configuration for the Host system by scanning the Hardware configuration (dmesg or any other resources) once booted into a generic kernel?

Or are there any on line database which contains optimal configuration for well known products (ie. Thinkpad T430) ?

I have configured kernels for myself but I find disabling the AMD features while compiling for an Intel and vice versa, very frustrating. If there is such a database,the compilation would be as easy as applying the software patches and executing make.

Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

The best available tool to do as you ask is built into the Linux kernel build system `make localmodconfig`

localmodconfig will still ask you a lot of questions and you are still likely to be unhappy. Better is to stick with the configuration used by whatever distro you favor.

Comment: IS it a good idea to create a website to store user submitted kconfigs in a database and make it available to download for everyone ?

Comment: It really does not matter what I think. What matters is what you think. My honest opinion, I do not think so. For most Linux users there is not a great deal of benefit in compiling their own kernel. I have come to really enjoy not having to compile my own kernels. That said I ran a custom kernel a few months ago when my laptop was brand new and I would have liked a website like that. I am sure the Gentoo crowd would love a website like that.